# Print method for multiple matrices

Tags: r, matrix

Could someone please suggest a method to `print` several matrices side by side in the terminal window.

For the matrices `m1` and `m2`, I would like the desired output below.

```
m1 <- m2 <- matrix(1:4, nrow=2, dimnames=list(c("a", "b"), c("d", "e")))
```

Desired output

```
m1      m2  
  d e     d e
a 1 3   a 1 3
b 2 4   b 2 4
```

The reason is that I have several 2x2 matrices that i am using in calculations and want to show in a Rmarkdown doc. It takes up a bit too much of the page when printing length ways. Thanks.

EDIT

My attempt at a solution

```
fn <- function(x) setNames(data.frame(.=paste("  ", rownames(x)), x, 
             check.names=F, row.names=NULL),c(paste(substitute(x)), colnames(x)))
cbind(fn(m1), fn(m2))
#     m1 d e   m2 f g
#1     a 1 3    v 1 3
#2     b 2 4    w 2 4
```

But this of course doesnt look very good.

Comment: Do you need to be able to access the values, or is it purely aesthetic?  Meaning can the print method be made of strings instead of numeric values?

Comment: Hi, @RichardScriven. No,I don't need to access/calculate with them, it is to `print` on the screen.

Comment: Yes, I thought it may be tricky, but thank you for looking at it. The best i can do is `fn <- function(x) data.frame(.=paste("  ", rownames(x)), x, check.names=F, row.names=NULL) ; cbind(fn(m1), fn(m2))` which isnt quite there.

Comment: I was trying things with `capture.output(list(m1=m1, m2=m2))` and then messing around with `cat` on the result.  Basically like a side-by-side list

Comment: hmm, forgot about capture.output, that is maybe a way to go. ill have a look. Thanks.

Comment: I tried hacking it together as a data frame: `cbind(m1, data.frame("." = c("", ""), "m2" = rownames(m2)), m2)`. This isn't exactly what you want, but it's a step in that direction?

Comment: Thanks for your help Sean, yes that's kind of going along the same route as i was but i don't think the data.frame approach looks great. I think this is difficult as its not a particularly sensible thing to be doing - it is only for aesthetics. I foresee a cut and paste job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little hack-ish, but I believe it is what you want:

```
m1 <- m2 <- m3 <- m4 <- matrix(1:4, nrow=2, dimnames=list(c("a", "b"), c("d", "e")))
fn <- function(x) setNames(data.frame(.=paste("", rownames(x)), x, check.names=F, row.names=NULL),c(" ", colnames(x)))
matrix.names <- Filter( function(x) 'matrix' %in% class( get(x) ), ls(pattern = "m") )
matrix.list <- lapply(matrix.names, get)
matrix.chain <- do.call(cbind, lapply(matrix.list, fn))
cat(" ", paste0(matrix.names, collapse = "     "), "\n"); print(matrix.chain, row.names = FALSE)
  m1     m2     m3     m4 
    d e    d e    d e    d e
  a 1 3  a 1 3  a 1 3  a 1 3
  b 2 4  b 2 4  b 2 4  b 2 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `cat` method works great.

Comment: This solution is not at all general.   Can someone turn it into a function taking an arbitrary list of matrices?