# R: get names of arguments passed in `...`

Tags: r, parameter-passing, expression-evaluation

In a simple function using `...` to supply a list of arguments, is it possible for that function to find the **names** of the objects passed from the **calling** environment?  If so, how?

This arises in the context of the question, [printing matrices and vectors side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419622/printing-matrices-and-vectors-side-by-side), but is probably more general.

In that context, the arguments `...` can also include character strings, for which no names are required.  Here is my MWE, where I tried using `deparse(substitute())`, but to no avail.

```
test_names <- function(...) {
  # get arguments
  args <- list(...)
  chars <- sapply(args, is.character)
  names <- sapply(args, function(x) if(is.character(x)) " " else deparse(substitute(x)))
  names
}
```

Test:

```
A = matrix(c(0.5, 1, 3, 0.75, 2.8, 4), nrow = 2)
x = c(0.5, 3.7, 2.3)
y = c(0.7, -1.2)
b = A %*% x - y

> test_names(A, " * ", x, " - ", y, " = ", b)
[1] "X[[i]]" " "      "X[[i]]" " "      "X[[i]]" " "      "X[[i]]"
>
```

My desired output for this would be the character vector of length 7:

```
[1] "A"  " "   "x" " "  "y" " "   "b"
```

It is surprising here that the results are all `X[[i]]`, when there is no `X` mentioned anywhere.

Following @Roland's answer, this seems to do what I want:

```
test_names2 <- function(...) {
  argnames <- sys.call()
  unlist(lapply(argnames[-1], as.character))
}

> test_names2(A, " * ", x, " - ", y, " = ", b)
[1] "A"   " * " "x"   " - " "y"   " = " "b"
```

Comment: You get those from lapply. It doesn't preserve list names.

Comment: Edited to show desired output

Answer (score 13):

Use `sys.call`:

```
test_names <- function(...) {
  argnames <- sys.call()
  paste(lapply(argnames[-1], as.character), collapse = "")
}
#[1] "A * x - y = b"
```

Answer (score 7):

As the email list describes ([here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-September/288786.html)) either `sys.call` as Roland said or `match.call` can be used for this.

In comparison to Roland's solution, a solution with `match.call` looks like

```
f = function(...){
  return(match.call())
}

d = f(x = 1, b = 5)
d
#f(x = 1, b = 5)
as.list(d[-1])
#$x
#[1] 1
#
#$b
#[1] 5
```

So use it somewhat like this, because the first element is the name of the function itself.

```
f = function(...){
  return(as.list(match.call())[-1])
}
```

---

They are similar, but the [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.call.html) says:

> sys.call() is similar [*to match.call()*], but does not expand the
>   argument names;

So here's one difference.